# mozfullscreenchange not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, onchange

I am trying to add an event on screen change (full/default). The given function well work in chrome but not working in firefox.

```
if (myid.addEventListener){
    myid.addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange' , changeScreen , false)
    myid.addEventListener('mozfullscreenchange' , changeScreen , false)
    myid.addEventListener('fullscreenchange' , changeScreen , false)
    myid.addEventListener('MSwebkitfullscreenchange' , changeScreen , false)
}

else {
    myid.attachEvent('fullscreenchange' , changeScreen)
}
function changeScreen(){
    if (mydiv.id != 'oldid') {
        mydiv.id = 'oldid'
    }
    else {
        mydiv.id = 'newid'
    }
}
```

What i am going wrong. Please no J Query. Only JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

The 'mozfullscreenchange' is an event of the document which contain the element (in this case, I think 'myid' is the element).

So, I think you can modify your code:

```
if (myid.addEventListener){
    myid.addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange' , changeScreen , false)
    document.addEventListener('mozfullscreenchange' , changeScreen , false)
    myid.addEventListener('fullscreenchange' , changeScreen , false)
    myid.addEventListener('MSwebkitfullscreenchange' , changeScreen , false)
}
```

You can find more information about 'mozfullscreenchange' in this link (Notification section): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API